# WebDriver Capture Text by XPath

Tags: xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to capture a line of text for an automated WebDriver test to use it in a comparison later on.  However, I cannot find an XPath that will work with WebDriver.  I have used the text() function before to capture text that is not in a tag, but in this instance that is not working.  Here is the HTML, note that this text will never be the same, so I cannot use contains or similar functions.

```
<div id="content" class="center ui-content" data-role="content" role="main">
<div data-iscroll="scroller">
<div class="ui-corner-all ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical" data-role="controlgroup">
<a class="ui-btn ui-corner-top ui-btn-hover-c" style="text-align: left" data-role="button" onclick="onDocumentClicked(21228772, "document.php?loan=********&folderseq=0&itemnum=21228772&pageCount=3&imageTypeName=1003 Application - Final&firstInitial=&lastName=")" href="#" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-top">
<span class="ui-btn-text">
<img class="checkMark checkMark21228772 notViewedCompletely" width="15" height="15" title="You have not yet viewed this document." src="../images/white_dot.gif"/>
1003 Application - Final. (Jan 11 2012  5:04PM)
</span>
</span>
</a>
```

In this example, the text I am attempting to capture is: 1003 Application - Final. (Jan 11 2012  5:04PM)
I have inspected the element with Firebug and I have tried the following XPaths with no success.

```
html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/a[1]/span/span
html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/a[1]/span/span/text()
```

The WebDriver test is being written in C#.

Comment: Can't you simply get the element and call [`getText()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText%28%29)?

Comment: GetText returns an empty string using the selector in Alexander's answer below.  I get an timeout or invalid path exception when using the locators posted in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by removing the span tags from the XPath.

```
GetText("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/a[1]", SelectorType.XPath);
```

Comment: I have this same problem and I tried your solution, but im finding a error "SelectorType cannot be resolved to a variable". Is there anything I have to import or declare?

Comment: SelectorType is an enum I created to hold the element selectors that WebDriver supports.  I pass this to my WebDriver wrapper methods so they know what selector is being used for the string sent with it (the above is calling driver.FindElement(By.XPath(locator))).

Answer (score 1):

You can either use this

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[@id='content']/following-sibling::span[@class='ui-btn-text']")
```

or

```
var elem = driver.FindElement(By.Id("Content"));
string text = string.Empty;
if(elem!=null) {
   var textElem = elem.FindElement(By.Xpath(".//following-sibling::span[@class='ui-btn-text']"));
   if(textElem!=null) text = textElem.Text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

python webdriver code looks something like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='ui-btn-text']").text
```

But locator may be not uniqe, because I can't see all the code

PS Try to never use locators like `html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/a[1]/span/span`

Comment: "GetText returns an empty string using the selector in Alexander's answer below"

use the firebug+firepath in Firefox browser to check if locator is uniqe

Comment: How does one do this?  I know how to inspect the firepath, but I don't know how to tell if this locator is unique.

Comment: Copy the xpath to firepath's xpath line and press 'Enter'. It will tell you how many matches are found

Comment: Using the XPath you provided, there are 37 matches so it is not unique.  Can you index these to get the first match?

Comment: I need more html code, at least `div/a[1]/span/span` this part. Or if the page is available in public I could give you the exact XPath. And please tell the programming language you're using

Comment: I edited the original question and added more code.  There are several more class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c sections, and after the final there is a </div> tag.  I didn't want to paste them all since they are practically the same as the first.

Answer (score 0):

Approach:
Find the CSS Selector from the Given DOM

Derived CSS:css=#content div.ui-controlgroup > a[onclick*='onDocumentClicked'] > span > span

Use the C# Library Method to get the Text.